# In Next Js images are not loading

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I have a problem with images in Next JS. Images come from API (Node js). First of all I am new about Next JS. I don't know what is my mistake.

[image]

My main component and API.

```
const ServicesPage = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="main-page-services-cards">
        {posts.map((card, key) => (
           <div key={card.id} className="service-card">
             <Link href={`/services/${card.id}`}>
              <a>
               <div className="card-img">
                <Image src={card.img} alt="Services" />
               </div>
               <h4>{card.header}</h4>
               <p>{card.p}</p>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ServicesPage;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/servicesApi/");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}
```

My API. Data come from data.js (this is example data)

```
import { servicesData } from "../../../data";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(servicesData);
}
```

My data.js

```
import icon1 from "./public/images/window-alt.svg";

export const servicesData = [
  {
    img: icon1,
    header: "Saytların yaranması",
    p: "Ex similique necessitatibus cumque. Autem velit velit ",
    id: 1,
    slug: "saytlarin-yaranmasi",
  },
 
]
```

Comment: Are the images hosted on a different address to nextjs server?

Comment: can we have ur `posts` array?

Comment: try to use like this: `<Image src={card.img.src} alt="Services" />`

Comment: @zrna not working. Same error

Comment: Pass the path to the image in `img` rather than the imported image itself, e.g. `img: "/images/window-alt.svg"`.

Comment: @juliomalves I tried like this ```img: "/public/images/window-alt.svg",``` and did not work

Comment: Remove the `/public`, literally use `img: "/images/window-alt.svg"`.